# Entity Framework DBContext global caching?

Tags: c#, linq, caching, entity-framework-4, dbcontext

(EF4.1 - 4.0 framework)

Most of the code examples on the web dictate best practice on Entity Framework; they say wrap your usage of the DBContext in a using block so as to assure stateless operations. Even still, I'm getting what appears to be shared caching error.

ERROR

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.

Having looked around, the examples of this occur when someone shares a global instance of the DBContext amongst many calls.

I however receive this on the second call to the following function which lives in a static data access layer service class.

```
public static void UpdateRollout(Rollout rollout)
        {

               using (ITAMEFContext db = new ITAMEFContext(ConnectionStrings.XYZConnectionString))
                {
                    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

                    FixUp(rollout);


                    db.Rollouts.Attach(rollout);
                    db.Entry(rollout).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

                    db.SaveChanges();

                    //db.Entry(rollout).State = System.Data.EntityState.Detached;

                }

}



private static void FixUp(Rollout rollout)
        {
            // ensure manual fixup of foreign keys
            if (rollout.RolloutState != null)
                rollout.FK_RolloutState_ID = rollout.RolloutState.ID;
            if (rollout.Lead != null)
                rollout.RolloutLead_FK_User_ID = rollout.Lead.ID;
        }
```

The EFContext was generated via EF 4.x DBContext Fluent Generator which references a edmx model .

[image: edmx model picture]

Looks like this.

```
public partial class ITAMEFContext : DbContext
{
    static ITAMEFContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ITAMEFContext>(null);
    }

    public ITAMEFContext() : base("name=ITAMEFContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    }

    public ITAMEFContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public ITAMEFContext(string nameOrConnectionString, DbCompiledModel model) : base(nameOrConnectionString, model)
    {

    }

    public ITAMEFContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    {

    }

    public ITAMEFContext(DbConnection existingConnection, DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection) : base(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Asset_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetAllocation_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetAssignee_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetAssigneeType_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetDeAllocation_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetState_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AssetType_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Department_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Location_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ManagementGroup_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Role_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Rollout_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RolloutState_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServiceArea_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Software_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SoftwareType_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new SubTeam_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new sys_UserLock_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Team_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new User_Mapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new WorkingMethod_Mapping());
    }

    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetAllocation> AssetAllocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetAssignee> AssetAssignees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetAssigneeType> AssetAssigneeTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetDeAllocation> AssetDeAllocations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetState> AssetStates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AssetType> AssetTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ManagementGroup> ManagementGroup { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ServiceArea> ServiceAreas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubTeam> SubTeams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WorkingMethod> WorkingMethods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Rollout> Rollouts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RolloutState> RolloutStates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SoftwareType> SoftwareTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<sys_UserLock> sys_UserLock { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to call UpdateRollout from my BL layer as many times as is necessary. 
The UI will need to keep a hold on the POCO Rollout entity graph which is returned as part of a previously fetched List.

Rollout and all other Entities are pure POCO, and no context tracking is desired.

I read that any context caching/tracking is obliterated once the using block disposes of the ITAMEFContext. However it appears there is some sort of global cache underling any instance of a DBContext in the same application domain??  I have to be honest and say so far EF appears to be more work than using good old stored procedures for layered apps.

The POCO.

```
public partial class Rollout
{
    public Rollout()
    {
        this.AssetAssignees = new HashSet<AssetAssignee>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RolloutLead_FK_User_ID { get; set; }
    public string EmailContacts { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Schedule { get; set; }
    public int FK_RolloutState_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NotificationDays { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssetAssignee> AssetAssignees { get; set; }
    public virtual User Lead { get; set; }
    public virtual RolloutState RolloutState { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:

The mapping.

```
 internal partial class Rollout_Mapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Rollout>
{
    public Rollout_Mapping()
    {                   
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);     
        this.ToTable("Rollout");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        this.Property(t => t.RolloutLead_FK_User_ID).HasColumnName("RolloutLead_FK_User_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.EmailContacts).HasColumnName("EmailContacts").HasMaxLength(500);
        this.Property(t => t.Schedule).HasColumnName("Schedule");
        this.Property(t => t.FK_RolloutState_ID).HasColumnName("FK_RolloutState_ID");
        this.Property(t => t.NotificationDays).HasColumnName("NotificationDays");
        this.Property(t => t.Notes).HasColumnName("Notes");
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Lead).WithMany(t => t.Rollouts).HasForeignKey(d => d.RolloutLead_FK_User_ID);
        this.HasRequired(t => t.RolloutState).WithMany(t => t.Rollouts).HasForeignKey(d => d.FK_RolloutState_ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `EntityState` of rollout before attaching it. if it's attached, Detach it first (if you set a navigation property to a tracked entity the new entity is automatically added).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar problem and, like you, I thought it was some kind of global caching causing the problem.

My use case was this:

1. using a new DbContext, set up some test data on my database then dispose the DbContet
2. run a system test on my application
3. Reset the database to a baseline state (I was doing this outside of EF)
4. Repeat from step 1 for the next system test

Everything ran fine for the first test, but on the second test I was getting the duplicate key error.

This had me stumped for a while, until I realised that a factory method I was using to build some of my test data **entities** was creating them as static objects; the second time through the loop, as soon as I added these static entities to the context, the full object graph from these entities was re-added, so when I later came to add other entities, they were already there.

Here's a simplified example...

Loop 1:

1. Create object A (static). Save changes [Database now contains A]
2. Create object B (not static) which has a relationship with object A. Save Changes [Database now contains A and B]
3. Reset database [Database now contains nothing]

Loop 2:

1. Create object A (static, so not actually recreated. Still contains reference to B even though this is not in the database). Save changes [Database now contains A and B]
2. Create object B (not static). Save changes. [BOOM! duplicate key because B is already in the database]

***Solution:*** I changed my factory method so that none of my entities were static. Problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT  - I have rewritten my answer.  Two points.

1: I found this article about EF DbContext life time (it refers to ObjectContext, but same rules apply):
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx

Note that the DbContext is not thread safe.  Since you are using a static method, you might be running into threading issues.  It might be worthwhile to create your DbContext where you need it instead of doing it in a static class.

2: Ideally you read and write in the same instance of DbCntext.  "Disconnected" just means that your entities are in memory while you are working with them, and the DbContext is tracking changes you made.

We use an approach more like this (pseudo-code):

```
 public class RolloutManager {
   ...
   // If you just update state and you have no input from somewhere else, you can just  
   // read and write in the same method
   public void UpdateRolloutState() {
       using( var db = new MyDBContext() {
            var stuffToUpdate = db.Rollouts.Where(....).ToList();
            foreach(var stuff in StuffToUpdate){
                stuff.PropertyToUpdate = ....;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
   }

   // If you have inputs, pass them in (using a different object normally, such as a wcf 
   //contract or viewmodel), read them up from the db, update the db entities and save
   public void UpdateRolloutState(IEnumerable<InputRollout> stuffToUpdate) {
       using( var db = new MyDBContext() {
            foreach(var stuff in StuffToUpdate){
                var dbRollout = db.Rollouts.Find(stuff.Id);
                // copy properties you want to update
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
   }
```

I hope this helps - it might not be the solution but it might point you to finding one.

Comment: But how do you explain that the first call to `UpdateRollout` runs fine? Your remark "This object is probably already there" leaves the core issue unexplained. Further, `Find` will make a needless roundtrip to the database which the OP tries to prevent by attaching. And any changes in `rollout` itself are not saved. -1, sorry.

Comment: As above on this one. I would totally understand had I used the same context, since you have to check if it is already cached and update properties or use Find, however each call to this function would result in the context being disposed. Thus the second call should be a new context. This is what suggests that there is some hidden behaviour behind how the DBContext is working under the covers. It must be in some way maintaining sate regardless of how many times the DBContext is disposed, requiring the developer to discover this and approach this quite differently than some have suggested.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: I gave an example on how it is normally done.  You don't attach objects on your own and set the state on your own, you let Entity Framework do that.  It might be not be what is causing the issue, but I would start with doing it the standard way first, before trying to figure out why it doesn't work when I use it in a non-standard way.  As far as Find(), it will only go to the DB if it isn't already there.

Comment: @gabnaim There is no standard way. Attaching and setting state is perfectly viable. In their book _DbContext_, Lerman and Miller even make a complete case for doing that. Nevertheless, this is all beside the issue of global caching (which I can't believe happens, but the evidence seems irrevocable).

Comment: What is confusing is that by all accounts, DBContext.Find will have to go to the database to retrieve the record as it SHOULD NOT be in the DBContext object graph cache since it was disposed last time it was used, thus using attach saves a round trip, with the downside that u have to manage the state. So u have to 'attach' this will mark all child objects in the graph as 'Unchanged', then ur supposed to be able to select which objects u wish to update accordingly. I thought this is the only way u can work truly 'disconnected' across layers/ tiers with EF.I'm no expert in EF mind u :/

Comment: I rewrote my answer after some more research, I added how we normally handle the DbContext (no static methods) and an article about that DbContext is not thread safe, which might be the issue.  I hope this helps to get you started in a different solution you might try.

Comment: I take the point on thread safety, no multi threaded access is taking place on the static method however so the mind still boggles. Indeed we could use the Find method in either case which would round trip the database, and if a select is taking a long time this may compound performance problems. It's a triad-off between the work involved in FixUp and manual state management vs the work involved in writing the "stuff.PropertyToUpdate =" code. If both approaches result in the same amount of work then the attach would at least prevent a DB round trip. Also, FixUp could be templated.

Comment: One thing just occurred to me.  Make sure the key is initialized in your "rollout" object and that it is unique.  Also, maybe the error isn't on rollout... could it be rolloutState?